# How to change tomcat jmx password's file permission

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx

I am trying to secure JMX access on my local tomcat instance hosted on Windows platform.  I have created access and password files and plugged those using the following VM arguments:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file
```

But I am running into an issue during tomcat start-up: **Error: Password file read access must be restricted**.  I tried changing the password's file owner and access using file security tab but it doesn't seem to be working.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Follow the instructions on this [page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/security-windows.html) to protect the password file.

Answer (score 18):

[This](http://tech-eureka.blogspot.de/2014/09/how-to-secure-password-file-on-windows.html) will work on Windows 10 and 7.

In short:

1. open a windows command prompt in your ActiveMQ 'conf' folder.
2. use icacls (run 'icacls' without options for help) to change the owner to be 'you', in my case:

icacls jmx.password /setowner myuser

3. remove all inherited permissions:

icacls jmx.password /inheritance:r

4. grant minimal permissions to your user (read/write in this case):

icacls jmx.password /grant:r myuser:(r,w)

Comment: This also works on windows 10, very handy reply! But make sure you run the command prompt as Administrator.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me, in command prompt go to your file location and type,

```
cacls jmxremote.password /P [username]:R
```

Replace [username] with your own username