# JMX password read access issue

Tags: java, ubuntu, jmx

When I try to use JMX to monitor an application like this:

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999 \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
     JMX_tester
```

it tells me:

```
Error: Password file read access must be restricted:
       /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/management/jmxremote.password
```

Yet, when I use `chmod` to restrict the read access, it tells me:

```
Error: can't read password file
```

Am I going insane or something? How can I fix this?

This is Ubuntu btw, with the latest oracle jdk

Comment: Same issue for me on Windows.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Make sure the user you are using to run the java process have access to the file (owner/read permissions).

Try:

```
chmod 600 jmxremote.password
```

Plus I suggest you'll make your own password file and run it with

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=pwFilePath
```

All explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html).

Comment: Windows users, check this answer to another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6501127/1143126

Comment: But when authenticate=false is set why we need password ...?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar Check your property spelling, possible overrides, etc. in your configuration. It tends to be error prone. However, the `authenticate=false` really disables the password checks.

Comment: Any answers to this ?

Comment: @Radioactive to what question are you referring?

Comment: @EladTabak I was also getting the same issue inspite of having set the "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=": "false". So I my question was if it is set to false why is it looking for the password folder.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to bypass authentication try to use below parameters.

> ```
> -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
> -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
> -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=port
> -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
> ```