# Deployment issue with IntelliJ when moved to open-jdk 8u212

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, adoptopenjdk

We recently migrated our systems to open-jdk from oracle jdk. When I tried deploying my war application, Facing some issues with the same.

C:\Softwares\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\bin\catalina.bat run
[2019-06-14 05:19:12,449] Artifact expresso:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\Rohit.Bansal.IntelliJIdea2019.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_expresso_3"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Softwares\apache-tomcat-8.0.24"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Users\Rohit.Bansal.IntelliJIdea2019.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_expresso_3\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.212.04-openj9"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Softwares\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Softwares\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
port = 81
Error: Password file read access must be restricted:

```
C:\Users\Rohit.Bansal\.IntelliJIdea2019.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_expresso_3\jmxremote.password
    sun.management.AgentConfigurationError
        at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.checkPasswordFile(ConnectorBootstrap.java:577)
        at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:426)
        at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:262)
        at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:452)
        at java.lang.System.startSNMPAgent(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Thread.completeInitialization(Thread.java:168)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.completeInitialization(J9VMInternals.java:74)
    Exception in thread "main" java/lang/RuntimeException: sun.management.AgentConfigurationError
        at sun/management/Agent.error (Agent.java:526)
        at sun/management/Agent.startAgent (Agent.java:269)
        at sun/management/Agent.startAgent (Agent.java:452)
        at java/lang/System.startSNMPAgent (NativeMethod:4294967295)
        at java/lang/Thread.completeInitialization (Thread.java:168)
        at java/lang/J9VMInternals.completeInitialization (J9VMInternals.java:74)
    Disconnected from server
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JMX password read access issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220442/jmx-password-read-access-issue)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue here: debug a Webapp in Tomcat from IntelliJ, after updating AdoptOpenJDK to jdk-8.0.212.04-openj9 under Windows (in my case Windows 7).

My solution was to add the following parameter to the VM Options of my run config:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

Now it works as before.

It was somewhat difficult for me to find references to the problem, as in my case the error message was in German (cited here to augment the chances to get a result for other people searching for the German version):

```
Fehler: Lesezugriff auf Kennwortdatei muss eingeschränkt werden
```

Obviously, the chances to get meaningful results are somewhat lower. I have then changed the language to `en` by setting the VM Option `-Duser.language=en`.

I haven't found a central location to set these parameters, but what probably comes closest is to set the parameters in the template of the local tomcat run configuration.